# Por quê quando utilizo método save do spring boot ele altera a persistência do dado em vários lugares?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, maven, java-8

Fala pessoal, tudo bem?
No meu contexto, preciso fazer um método desfazer, dessa fora utilizando um objeto de array que salva na memória meu último dado persintência do banco e, quando salvo esse dado no array e chamo o método save (**do SpringBoot do JPA**), com o novo dado alterado no banco, esse método save, altera a persistência dentro do array.

```
public ResponseEntity putLoja(@Valid @RequestBody Loja atualizaLoja, @PathVariable int idLoja) {
        if (lojaRepository.existsById(idLoja)) {
            atualizaLoja.setId(idLoja);
            lojaRepository.save(atualizaLoja);
            pilhaLojaAuxiliar.push(lojaRepository.findById(idLoja).get());
            return ResponseEntity.status(200).build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(400).build();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, no seu caso a solução mais simples é executar a desestruturação do objeto crinado um novo, assim mantera a percistencia já que o dado do seu arrey não estara mais vinculado ao dado sendo salvo pelo metodo save()

```
public ResponseEntity putLoja(@Valid @RequestBody Loja atualizaLoja, @PathVariable int idLoja) {
    if (lojaRepository.existsById(idLoja)) {
        atualizaLoja.setId(idLoja);
        lojaRepository.save(atualizaLoja);
        //Solução aqui
        Loja lojaDataPast = lojaRepository.findById(idLoja).get()
        Loja lojaDataArray = new Loja();
        lojaDataArray.setId(idLoja);
        lojaDataArray.setNome(lojaDataPast.getNome())
        pilhaLojaAuxiliar.push(lojaDataArray);
        //Fim Solução
        return ResponseEntity.status(200).build();
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.status(400).build();
    }
}
```